# normal map error in mesh with subsurface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, materials, objects

I was making my character for study, I made the model with many vertices, then I made the retopology, so far so good, I put the color texture and the normal map, but when activating the subsurface, I had this problem as you can see keeps showing these imperfections in the character's neck.
Eevee does not have this problem.
when i disable subsurface the problem goes away
[image]